# Fixed Decimal Precision

Tags: c++

I am currently using

```
std::cout.precision(5);
```

to set the decimal precision of my outputs. However, I would rather have my 
output ALWAYS output 5 decimal places (right now it won't show 0's).
How would I change my code to reflect this?

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for [**`std::fixed`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) together with [**`std::setprecision`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
double f =1.1;
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << std::endl;
```

stdout

```
1.10000
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << a << std::endl; //output a with fixed precision 5
```

see here :[std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) for some example.

Answer (score 0):

write a println function that takes a floating point and use it instead of cout, internally calling cout with precision

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to do:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
std::cout.precision(x);
```